# Sluggish behaviour for ImageScroll using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

I am working on an application that has few image scrolls and then lands to a subscription page. Referring to the tutorial here: http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/, I developed the app that does the imagescroll for 5 times and then takes user to the subscription page.

However, the behaviour is very sluggigh for imagefragment -> imagefragment but is very fine when I change from imagefragment to listfragment.

I modified the imagefragment code like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e("ImageFragment", "Image updated");
    View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container,
            false);

    RelativeLayout iv = (RelativeLayout)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    switch (fragVal) {
    case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show registration form
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_screen1); break;
    case 1: // Fragment # 1 - This will show image
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_screen2); break;
    case 2: // Fragment # 2 - This will show image
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_screen3); break;
    case 3: // Fragment # 3 - This will show image
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_screen4); break;
    case 4: // Fragment # 4 - This will show image
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_screen5); break;
    case 5: // Fragment # 5 - This will show image
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_screen6); break;
    }       
    return layoutView;
}
```

and also added android:largeHeap="true" to the AndroidManifest.

Looks like it need memory optimization.